# Moving specific index of array to the left using Insertion Sort

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I am trying to do an insertion sort algorithm, where I have a pushLeft method that asks the user for an array and int index and pushes the index to the left until it is sorted. However, I am having a hard time coding it. Right now I have:

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>> void pushLeft(double[] testArray, int index) {
    for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        while (inOrder(testArray[i - 1], testArray[index]) == false) {
            testArray[i] = testArray[i - 1];
                }
        testArray[i] = testArray[index];
    }
}
```

Right now if I have a double[] testArray = {5, 7, 8, 9, 6} and I call pushLeft(testArray, 4), it returns 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0. I know that is because of it residing in the for loop, but I am unsure of how else I should do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that if you're iterating to the right (`i++`) then `testArray[i] = testArray[i - 1];` will result in something like `testArray[2] = testArray[1]; testArray[3] = testArray[2];...`, i.e. since you're starting at index 1 every element starting from that index will have the same value. When right shifting an array you need to start at the "end" end move to the left, so `i--`. That would result in something like `testArray[3] = testArray[2];testArray[2] = testArray[1];...`

Comment: One thing you should do is step through your code with a debugger and have a look what's happening. That should make the problem clearer. It might also help to map the algorithm and data at certain steps out on paper.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your response. I am editing my code with eclipse, so no errors, just getting the wrong output. But I'll try some paper and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

When you write over a value in an array, the computer doesn't remember the old value. The problem here is that you're writing over the value to the left, and then using that *same value* to update every value to the left. I've shown what is currently happening below.

Arrays are 0-indexed, so when I say index 3, I'm referring to the 4th element.

Step 1 (Original array):
5.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 6.0

Step 2 (Over-write value at index 3 with value at index 4):
5.0, 7.0, 6.0, 6.0

Step 3 (Over-write value at index 2 with value at index 4):
5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0

To prevent this, think about how to preserve the values in the array so you don't accidentally copy the same number.